# automatically insert variable into InputBox at runtime and/or code manipulation at runtime using VBcomponents blocks Edit-And-Continue in execution

Tags: vba, debugging, excel, inputbox

I have a two tiered question.  I had initially posted the first part, but it was flagged as duplicate due I think to a misunderstanding.  Here I post my whole steps so far:

I have a number of quizzes to grade that each generate an `inputBox` to search for a product code string in a given range.  Is it possible to pass a known string from a cell in this range (defined by MY CODE which calls THEIR sub) to an `inputBox` and continue as expected.  Particularly, I'm interested in automating grading as much as possible by not having to stop every `inputBox` to enter some string.  I'm assuming there may be an event handler for an `inputBox` appearing but haven't been able to find it anywhere.  Additionally, I haven't found a good way to "type" my string into the `inputBox` other than the `SendKeys` method.  Thanks.

I don't know if I was quite clear as to what I'm trying to do.  I have code as follows:

```
Sub BlackBoxTestingPart1()
        Dim myXLS As Excel.Workbook, quizNum As String, file As String
        Dim ws As Worksheet, compileWs As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
        Dim j As Integer, correct As Boolean, 
                    Dim counter As Integer, pathstring As String
        Dim i As Integer

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        'get root directory and filename for first student
        quizNum = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStr(ThisWorkbook.Name, " ") - 1)
        Set compileWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Compiled")
        pathstring = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & quizNum & " Submissions\"
        file = Dir(pathstring)
        On Error GoTo nextStudent

        i = 1
        Do While file <> ""
                'continue do loop if file is data file
                If file = "OtherProducts.xlsm" Or file = "OtherProducts.xlsx" _
                Or file = "Quiz8.xlsm" Or file = "Quiz8.xlsx" Or file = "oprodcuts.xlsx" _
                Or file = "Quiz08.xlsx" Or file = "Quiz08.xlsm" Or file = "OtherProducts_Quiz8_Conley.xlsx" Then GoTo NextLoop

                Set myXLS = Workbooks.Open(pathstring & file, 0)
                Set ws = myXLS.Sheets("Example 9.1")
                counter = 0
                'PART1
                j = 1
                'RUN STUDENT MACRO FROM THEIR WORKBOOK; THIS IS WHERE THE INPUT BOX IS OF INTEREST
                Application.Run ("'" & myXLS.Name & "'!FindPriceFromOtherFile")
                If MsgBox("Correct?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then counter = counter + 1
Start1:
                j = 2
                Application.Run ("'" & myXLS.Name & "'!FindPriceFromOther")
                If MsgBox("Correct?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then counter = counter + 1

Start2:
                'close their file
                myXLS.Close False
                Set myXLS = Nothing
                Set ws = Nothing
                [d1].Offset(i, 0) = counter
                'see if student did not close datafile
                For Each wb In Workbooks
                        If wb.Name <> "Quiz08 Compilation.xlsm" Then
                                [e1].Offset(i, 0) = 0
                                wb.Close
                                Exit For
                        Else
                                [e1].Offset(i, 0) = 1
                        End If
                Next
                i = i + 1
NextLoop:
                file = Dir()
        Loop
        Set compileWs = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit Sub

nextStudent:
        If j = 1 Then
                Resume Start1
        ElseIf j = 2 Then
                Resume Start2
        End If
End Sub
```

I have a folder with every students' workbook, and I plan to iterate over all of them and blackbox test their macro named "FindPriceFromOther" (or "FindPriceFromOtherField" for students who couldn't follow simply naming protocol).  Here is an unadulterated, prototypical version of their code:

```
Public Sub FindPriceFromOther()
        Dim thisPath As String
        thisPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
        Workbooks.Open (thisPath & "\otherproducts.xlsx")

        'All old code below
        Dim code() As String, price() As Currency
        Dim size As Integer

        Range("A4", Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Name = "Products"
        Range("B4", Range("B4").End(xlDown)).Name = "Prices"
        size = Range("Products").Rows.Count

        ReDim code(size)
        ReDim price(size)
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 1 To size
            code(i) = Range("Products").Cells(i)
            price(i) = Range("Prices").Cells(i)
        Next

        Workbooks("otherproducts.xlsx").Close  'ADDED

        Dim thiscode As String, thisPrice As Double

        thiscode = InputBox("Enter Code", "Capture Code")
        For i = 1 To size
            If thiscode = code(i) Then Exit For
        Next i
        thisPrice = price(i)

        'already given
        'Dim thiscode As String, thisPrice As Double
        MsgBox "The unit price of product code " & thiscode & " is " & _
            Format(thisPrice, "$0.00"), vbInformation, "Product found"

End Sub
```

So you can see their macro opens a data workbook, copies two ranges to two arrays, and then there is the `inputBox`; I am curious if there is any way to put one of the product codes (which maybe I could declare at runtime somehow BEFORE the `inputBox` is triggered) into the `inputBox` when it occurs.  Hope this makes what I want more clear.

EDIT: I finally got a start of some sort of code to work as follows:

I ended up sort of doing what I was trying to do, but needed to change the code of my student's submisssions.  This seems to me to be a very, very kludgy way of doing what I want though.

```
Public Sub BlackBoxTestingPart2()
        Dim myXLS As Excel.Workbook, quizNum As String, file As String
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet, compileWs As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim j As Integer, correct As Boolean, counter As Integer, pathstring As String
        Dim i As Integer, wb As Workbook, procedureType As Integer
        Dim closedFile As Boolean

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        procedureType = InputBox("1 for changing code, 2 for running macros", "Type of Execution")
        quizNum = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStr(ThisWorkbook.Name, " ") - 1)
        Set compileWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Compiled")
        pathstring = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & quizNum & " Submissions\"
        file = Dir(pathstring)
        On Error GoTo nextStudent

        i = 1
        Do While file <> ""
                If Not file Like "*######*" And Not file Like "*#####*" _
                        And Not file Like "*####*" Then GoTo NextLoop

                Set myXLS = Workbooks.Open(pathstring & file, 0)
                Set ws = myXLS.Sheets("Example 9.1")


                If procedureType = 1 Then
                j = 0
                        Call modifyCode(myXLS)
Start0:
                        myXLS.Close True
                        Set myXLS = Nothing
                        Set ws = Nothing
                ElseIf procedureType = 2 Then
                        counter = 0
                        'PART1
                        j = 1
                        Application.Run "'" & myXLS.Name & "'!FindPriceFromOtherFile"
                        'Application.Run myXLS.Name & "!FindPriceFromOtherFile"
                        If MsgBox("Correct?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then counter = counter + 1
Start1:
                        j = 2
                        Application.Run "'" & myXLS.Name & "'!FindPriceFromOther"
                        'Application.Run myXLS.Name & "!FindPriceFromOther"
                        If MsgBox("Correct?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then counter = counter + 1

Start2:
                        myXLS.Close False
                        Set myXLS = Nothing
                        Set ws = Nothing
                        closedFile = True
                        For Each wb In Workbooks
                                If wb.Name <> "Quiz08 Compilation.xlsm" Then
                                        closedFile = False
                                        wb.Close
                                        Exit For
                                End If
                        Next
                        Set wb = Nothing
                        [d1].Offset(i, 0) = counter
                        If Not closedFile Then
                                [e1].Offset(i, 0) = 0
                        Else
                                [e1].Offset(i, 0) = 1
                        End If


                        i = i + 1
                End If

NextLoop:
                file = Dir()
        Loop
        Set compileWs = Nothing

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit Sub

nextStudent:
        If j = 1 Then
                Resume Start1
        ElseIf j = 2 Then
                Resume Start2
        ElseIf j = 0 Then
                Resume Start0
        End If
End Sub

Sub modifyCode(wb As Workbook)
        Dim newCode As String, varName As String, j As Integer
        Dim cmpComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent

        newCode = " = ""L2201-2"""

        For Each cmpComponent In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
                If cmpComponent.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule Then
                        For j = 1 To cmpComponent.CodeModule.CountOfLines
                                If cmpComponent.CodeModule.Lines(j, 1) Like "* [=]*InputBox*" Then
                                        varName = Left(cmpComponent.CodeModule.Lines(j, 1), InStr(cmpComponent.CodeModule.Lines(j, 1), "=") - 1)
                                        cmpComponent.CodeModule.ReplaceLine j, varName & newCode
                                End If
                        Next j
                End If
        Next cmpComponent

        Set cmpComponent = Nothing

End Sub
```

So as you can see I included `modifyCode()` to replace the `inputBox` call in the student's code with just a value.  This code would be fine, but for some reason I couldn't solve another problem.  In the initial code first posted, this allowed for errors to be detected in the students' called macros as error handling can't go ACROSS workbooks; this was perfect in that the Edit-and-Continue feature worked fine (ie if syntax error in student's code, execution would cease, I could find their errors, and deduct points appropriately).  However, using the `modifyCode()` AND executing the student's macros somehow locked this convenient feature.  It threw a `Can't edit module` error but I couldn't find a good source of information on exactly why this happens (the only information was when using SourceSafe, which I am not).  Instead, I divided the testing into "Change Code" execution and "Run Macros" execution.  This worked, but as initially stated, it necessarily alters the students' code.
Please try and give me any insight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just want to be able to place a **Default** value in InputBox, check [Application.InputBox Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: I know how to do this for my code that is in my base workbook.  However, the `InputBox` occurs in the workbooks of the students which I am opening, executing their procedure, and closing one at a time; I am trying use my code to blackbox test their code, but want to automate the typing into their `InputBox` so that I don't have to manually enter a value each time one is displayed. I'm trying to do this without altering their code.  I essentially can implement your solution with my method already (actually I just replace their `InputBox` line of code with a given value).

Comment: You might be better off create a Public InputBox in your workbook, then search and replace student's InputBox string to use yours? So Student's InputBox arguments are passed to yours while you add default or return the simulated value to student's macro?

Comment: I have a tangential idea related to this, but just don't know how to implement it with my base knowledge of VBA.  Rather than still needing to replace their code with mine, is it possible for me to overload `InputBox` with some sort of Public InputBox method in my code.  Also can this method take precedence over the `Application.InputBox` that the students call in their code?  I don't know enough about how classes and inheritance work to effectively do this.  All said, I would still prefer to leave their code untouched to maintain its integrity.

Comment: Or even better yet is it possible to suspend the `Application.InputBox` method for the duration of the program to force a call to my `Public InputBox` instead? Then I could use a global incrementing variable to allow my `InputBox` to return a few values (boundary conditions naturally).